# Commenting methods in c

Tags: java, c, comments

I wonder if its okay to comment methods in c in the same way you comment code in java-language?

```
/**
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return
 */
protected boolean myMethod(int x, int y) {



  return true;
}
```

that is in the same manner in c

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return
 */
int myMethod(int x, int y) {



  return 1;
}
```

Of course its up to the programmer but I would like to know if c-programmers uses these @param or not?

Comment: I wish I have your problems. You can put almost anything into comments in C. Comments are removed by the preprocessor and they doesn't have any effect on  the final code.

Comment: @V-X: Why do you say: ***almost** everything?*

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: text */ is not a good content of the comment.

Comment: @V-X: Haha, I lolled :P

Comment: Pedantry, I know, but FYI `C` has only functions. No method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course its up to the programmer but I would like to know if
>   c-programmers uses these @param or not?

In C, whatever you put inside the `/**/` is treated as comments. But I dont think `@param` has got anything to do for it in **C.**

As far as `@` is concerned the `@` in Java is for the Javadoc functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Doc-comments like these are not commonly used in C. They may be useful in some IDEs to generate documentation for functions, but I don't recall ever seeing these comments in C source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for documentation in any programming languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D

Answer (score 1):

I like to comment my function definitions like such:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * @brief   
 * @author  
 * @date    
 * @return  
 * @arg
 * @note     
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to comment in any way that is easy to understand.  In java you comment in specific format to allow javadoc to generate documentation.

Instead of javadoc, in C(and many other languages) DOXYGEN is commonly used to generate documentation from structured comments.
Fortunately the syntax is almost identical with javadoc.

Check out http://www.doxygen.nl/.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` in Java is for the Javadoc functionality.  That is not a part of the C language, so the `@` would be ignored in a comment.  These type of things are usually team/company dependent and are a matter of convention.